# Input string was not in a correct format when parsed with TimeSpan.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datatable, timespan

I have a `DataTable` `dtTest`.

I want to parse one cell from this table from row 2 and colum 2
This cell can have a format of `hh:mm:ss or h:mm:ss`

I want to parse it to switch to format h.mm or hh.mm

here I verify if there is symbol "`:`" or not on position `2`

```
string typeTime = dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString().Substring(1, 1);
```

Now I parse them:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString(), 
    typeTime == "." ? "h'.'mm" : "hh'.'mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

After parsing it gives me an error "**Input string was not in a correct format**".

Comment: It looks your value can not be parsed. What is the actual value returned by dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString()?

Comment: @GregorPrimar  dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString() "08:00:00" string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to parse a string *exactly* - your string contains a seconds component that does not exist in your format strings. Your string also contains `:` where you specify `.`.

The following should work:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString(), 
    "h':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that the `h` format specifier will correctly understand `8` or `08`.

Additionally, you can simply use one of the [standard `TimeSpan` format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) - specifically `g` OR `c` instead of the custom format string:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString(), 
    "g", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeSpan.ParseExact(dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString(), 
    "c", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan s = TimeSpan.ParseExact(dtTest.Rows[2][2].ToString(), "g", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// zero based row and column index
var rows = dtTest.AsEnumerable();
var secondRow = rows.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
if (secondRow != null)
{
    String secondFieldText = secondRow.Field<String>(1);
    String format = secondFieldText.Length == 8 ? "hh:mm:ss" : "h:mm:ss";
    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(secondFieldText, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```